# Cron Job in Linux

Tags: linux, zip, cron

I am newbie just have a doubt,

I have a Outerl.sh to be executed on every zip  file arrival in FTP and get the **.sh file inside the zip file and execute that (*.sh) file which present inside the zip file.

Is this possible to execute the inner.sh using CronJobs Outer.sh.........?

Please help me to understatnd.Below is the just example structure.

```
***Outerl.sh
    --toexecute every file comes
FTP
  --file1.zip
  --file2.zip

file1
      --**.xml
      --**.doc
      --cronInner.sh
```

Comment: Yes it is possible

Comment: Thankyou, Please make it is as answer if you can show some reference give link with answer or will delete this question.

Comment: Hope the answer suits your particular requirements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `Outer.sh` script the ftp files will be extracted. 
Assuming that the files will be placed in a directory where no other files exist, and that the .sh files that have been ftp'd are ***safe*** to execute.

`Outer.sh`

```
# read files in ftp directory
# extract zip files to tmp directory

cd tmp
for f in *.sh
do
   chmod +x $f  # ensure executable
   ./$f         # execute "inner" script
done

# remove files from tmp directory
```

Comment: +1 for *safe*. Bear in mind that anyone who acquires the ability to ftp files to that account can execute anything they like -- it doesn't have to be a shell script to end in `.sh`.